# What is the name of this validation procedure?

Tags: machine-learning, validation

I have a set of classified data. In order to test the precision of several algorithms- I split the data into train and test sets. For the test set I choose at random 30% of the data and the rest is for the train set. I do $N$ iterations in which I split the data this way and take the average precision of the $N$ iterations.

Does this validation procedure has a specific name?

Comment: CrossValidation? :)

Comment: that looks more like repeated hold out with a 70/30 split, if you are sampling without replacement, bagging if you are sampling with replacement.

Comment: @CloseToC I need to distinguish this validation from the k-fold cross validation, so the name "CrossValidation" is not what I am searching for.

Comment: @image_doctor "Repeated holdout" -> this is what I was looking for. You can add the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like repeated hold trials out with a 70/30 split.